# Is it possible to get property name from extension method

Tags: c#, extension-methods

Let's say I have this method that gets string as a extension parameter:

```
private static List<string> ValidationErrors = new List<string>();

private static void ErrorCheck<T>(this string str)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
    {
        // This just returns "str"                                                                    
        // Instead of property name (see "How I use" section")
        ValidationErrors.Add(typeof(T).Namespace + "[" + nameof(str) + "]");
    }
}
```

And this is how I use it:

```
Car.Color.ErrorCheck<Car>();
```

Where Car object's Color is just string property. So what I want is to get "Color" instead of "str" in my extension method.

Any ideas how I could achieve this?

Comment: `Car.Color.ErrorCheck<Car>()` The fact that you could mismatch types (e.g. `Car.Color.ErrorCheck<User>()`) should clue you in that your current system is flawed. When you pass a string as a parameter, there is no way to know where that string originally came from (`Car.Color` in your case). A much more workable solution (and less prone to developer error) would be something like `Car.ErrorCheck(x => x.Color)`

Comment: Yeah, thanks! Didn't think of that before your comment. Seems legit.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible. C# has a few options:

- `nameof`

  ```
    nameof(Car.Color)
  ```
- Expression trees using `Expression<...>` and lambdas. See this post: [Retrieving Property name from lambda expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671968/retrieving-property-name-from-lambda-expression)

Comment: Why did you reopen the question? It was a valid duplicate. Just to answer yourself and link the duplicate target?

Comment: @PatrickHofman its not an exact duplicate. theres the `nameof` approach as well.

Comment: Then you should have added that to the duplicate target, not reopen the question.